# How can I use "pretend" in negative way?

Tags: verb-usage

I played the game called "SPY". There were one spy out of ten. Nobody knows who is the spy except the spy. After the game, I wanted to say "He pretended to be a spy." and "He pretended not to be a spy."

- He pretended to be a spy. 
  I think this sentence is right.

Then "He pretended not to be a spy." is right? I mean, he tried to hide the fact that he is a spy.

And one more question.
Can I say like this?

- He pretended a spy.
- He pretended not a spy.

If I cannot say, could you give me right grammar sentence? And I wanna know why I'm wrong.

Plus, I want to learn how I can say this in other way using the other verb or expression.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off saying what the spy was trying to do than what they weren't, for example

> The spy was impersonating a diplomat

That means that the spy was pretending to be a diplomat instead of a spy.

For your sentence, the only correct one is

> He pretended not to be a spy

you might also say

> He concealed the fact that he was a spy

Slightly fancier ways of talking about spies:

> The spy concealed his true profession

or

> The spy used subterfuge to conceal his true motives

Comment: I added the situation. It was just a game. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

> Then "He pretended not to be a spy." is right? I mean, he tried to
>   hide the fact that he is a spy.

Your usage of negative infinitive is fine but the sentence seems not to be quite correct, because it sounds to me that it doesn't explain very well the fact that the male character did something just to hide that he is not a spy.
You may want to say:

**The spy pretended to be an ordinary citizen (or diplomat, soldier, etc.).**

Pretend is both a transitive and intransitive verb. This means that according to the sentence, it takes or not a direct object. Please check the related definition [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pretend_1?q=pretend). For this reason, the sentences

- He pretended a spy.
- He pretended not a spy.

are **wrong**. You may mean:

- **He pretended to be a spy**.
- **He pretended not to be a spy**.
- **He pretended that he wasn't a spy**.

Comment: I added the situation. It was just a game. Ty.